# Routing an HTTP request through remote host

Tags: html, routes, spoofing

I'm curious is it possible to route an http get request through a remote host, which is not on a local network and behind a router?  So the source ip address of the http packet will have a remote host ip adress, I don't need a reply from a final web server.
Thank you